# Is there a way to force a linked file to open and not be able to open in the Browser?

Tags: 2013

I have files that dont work in the browser view and want them to directly open in the software is the a way to do this?

Comment: what are the files type?

Answer (score 1):

To open documents [in the client application](http://blog.sharepointgeek.nl/post/2014/07/22/how-to-configure-the-default-open-behavior-for-Office-documents-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx), activate the feature **"Open Documents in Client Application by Default feature**".

Also check this one

[Configure SharePoint Server to Open Office Documents in Client Application by Default](http://blogs.technet.com/b/officeasia/archive/2013/01/09/configure-sharepoint-server-to-open-office-documents-in-client-application-by-default.aspx)